# CSS: Style <a> tags to look like plain text

Tags: html, css

How can I style an anchor tag to look exactly like plain text? For example, I have:

```
<p> Here is some text and here is a 
   <a class='no-link' href="http://www.example.com" >link</a></p>
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
.no-link{
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: text;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

However, with this styling, the 'link' text will still show the default cursor (i.e. the arrow) when you hover over it, as opposed to the 'text' cursor which shows up on the rest of the text in the `<p>` tag. How can I make all of it have the text cursor and *still* have the link *not* be clickable?

I would like to avoid using jQuery, or even JavaScript at all if possible.

Comment: You're using an anchor tag which shouldn't look like a link and shouldn't be clickable? Of course I have to ask why you're using an anchor tag in the first place... If it's unavoidable, you can solve your problem by using `.no-link:hover{...`, which will apply styles to any element with the `no-link` class that is being hovered over.

Comment: Can you make us a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: It looks like `pointer-events` is on the way out, at least in Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162757#c64
 and http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-pointer-events/2014JulSep/0051.html

Comment: @mowwwalker I know it seems odd but I need them to be anchor tags because I want to be able to easily make them clickable at a later point in time, without having to rewrite parts of the DOM. The selector `.no-link:hover{}` is just a more specific selector to the one I mentioned in my original post so that has the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution would be to add `cursor:text` to the parent `p` element. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksL5trky/)

```
p {
    cursor:text;
}
.no-link {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

---

Alternatively, a less optimal solution would be to overlay a pseudo element, thus preventing it from being clickable [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/zw57o6d2/). The down-side to this solution is that nothing within the paragraph would be clickable. This would therefore not work if you wanted normal links in the same paragraph element.

```
p:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    cursor:text;
}
```

As a side note, I'd suggest using the value `inherit` for the link's color. In doing so, it will match the parent element's color if it happens to change... like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/oxwasygm/).